# Enable linter rules to use `useEffect` instead of `React.useEffect` (named export instead of full export)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, eslint, javascript-import

In our codebase we always wanna use

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';
```

instead of

```js
import React from 'react';
// use in code as `React.useEffect`
```

Is it possible to achieve it with eslint longer rules? If yes then how?

Are there existing solutions?
And if there isn't existing solution then how to write a custom one?

We wanna use such rules only for the *react* dependency.

Comment: So, what's stopping you from using `import { useEffect } from 'react';`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [no-restricted-imports](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-restricted-imports) to limit the import of `React` (default):

```json
"no-restricted-imports": [
  "error",
  {
    "paths": [
      {
        "name": "react",
        "importNames": ["default"],
        // "message": "some messages for who import 'React' accidentally"
      }
    ]
  }
],
```